# Dynamically parse multiple json array objects with php

Tags: php, json

I have a json file as below name "brands.json"

```
{
   "title":"List of brands",
   "version" : 1,
   "nike": [
    {"type":"shoes","size":10,"color":"black"},
    {"type":"shirt","size":"S","color":"black"}
   ],
   "converse": [
    {"type":"shoes","size":10,"color":"red"},
    {"type":"backpack","size":"N/A","color":"red"}
   ],
   "champion": [
    {"type":"shoes","size":10,"color":"blue"},
        {"type":"pants","size":"M","color":"grey"}      
    ]
}
```

I looked at some example online and get this piece of code

```
<?php
        $read = file_get_contents("report.json");
        $json = json_decode($read, true);
        foreach($json as $key => $val){
            if(is_array($val)){
                echo "$key : <br>";
                foreach($key as $k => $v){
                    echo "$k => $v<br>";
                }
            }       
            else {
                echo "$key => $val<br>";            
            }
        }
    ?>
```

I would be able to print out

title => List of brands

version => 1

nike :

converse :

champion :

But I would like to get the array inside of those brands. I was thinking of having a `foreach` loop inside the if statement. However, it returns errors

> nike :  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach().

Some resources suggested to do something like `$json->nike as $item => $v` but that will be redundant since I also have converse and champion arrays. If someone could direct me to a good resource or provide a code example, it'd be very much appreciated.

Expected table
Nike:

type | size | color

shoes| 10   | black

shirt| S    | black

Comment: The `foreach` loop should work. Show what you tried that's getting the error, and show the exact error message.

Comment: @Barmar I updated my post with what I think foreach should be like and the message

Comment: What are you actually want as output? Do you really want `type => t-shirt` and so on?

Comment: @Andreas yes `type => t-shirt` and so on. @Moch. Rizal Rachmadani's anwer helps me a lot.

Comment: Ok... I just find that odd. You could just have print_r the array then. Usually you want the output to be "nicer" than that.

Comment: @Andreas since I want to put those inputs into a table

Comment: If you want it in a table then why not ask how to put it in a table instead of asking how to `type => t-shirt`?

Comment: @Andreas I thought I would figure out how to do that if I can get the data one by one. But it seems like a difficult task. Do you have any idea on how to put those into table?

Comment: Depends on how you want the table to look like

Comment: @Andreas I added my expected table in the post

Comment: The array is `$val`, why are you doing `foreach ($key ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create function that buffers output and display it

```
    $read = '{
       "title":"List of brands",
       "version" : 1,
       "nike": [
        {"type":"shoes","size":10,"color":"black"},
        {"type":"shirt","size":"S","color":"black"}
       ],
       "converse": [
        {"type":"shoes","size":10,"color":"red"},
        {"type":"backpack","size":"N/A","color":"red"}
       ],
       "champion": [
        {"type":"shoes","size":10,"color":"blue"},
            {"type":"pants","size":"M","color":"grey"}      
        ]
    }';

    $json = json_decode($read, true);

    // this function will run recursively
    function display($val){
       // create output buffer variable
        $output = "";
       // check is array or not
        if(is_array($val)){
            // check is multimensional or not
            if(isset($val[0])){
                foreach($val as $v){
                    $output .= "<br/>".display($v);
                }
            }else{
                foreach($val as $k => $v){
                    $output .= $k." => ".display($v)."<br/>";
                }
            }      
        }else{
            // append output if it just a value
            $output .= $val;
        }
        return $output;
    }

    echo display($json);

?>
```

Preview
https://code.sololearn.com/wkeim4HQO9zP#php